# Upper Bound on codes (McEliece)

Tags: coding-theory

I try to understand the proof of McEliece, Rodemich, Rumsey, Welch for a new upper bound of a Code.

They define

$P(x)=\frac{ 2 }{ t+1 } \begin{pmatrix} n \\ t \end{pmatrix} \left[K_{ t+1 }(x)K_{t}(a)-K_{t}(x)K_{t+1}(a) \right] \sum_{k=0}^t{\frac{ K_{k}(x)K_{k}(a) }{\begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix}  }  } $

with Krawtchouk Polynomial

$K_{k}(x) = \sum_{j=0}^k{ (-1)^{j} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ j \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} n-x \\ k-j \end{pmatrix} (q-1)^{k-j}}$.

They proof the upper bound

$M_{LP  }(n,d)\leq H_{2}(\frac{ 1 }{ 2 }-\sqrt{ \delta(1-\delta) })$,

where H is the entropy function.

I do understand the proof itself, but I'm having issues with the following intermediate step:

$M_{LP  }(n,d)\leq \frac{ P(0) }{ \lambda_{0} }$

$\lambda_{0}$ is given by

$\lambda_{0}=-\frac{2  }{t+1  }\begin{pmatrix} n \\ t \end{pmatrix}K_{t+1}(a)K_{t}(a)$.

I tried to compute $\lambda_{0}$ on my own but I got no result.

It is known that:

$\lambda_{k}=q^{ -n }\sum_{i=0}^n{ P(i) }K_{i}(k)$

and so it follows for q=2

$\lambda_{0}=\frac{ 1 }{ 2^{n} } \sum_{i=0}^n P(i) \begin{pmatrix} n \\ i \end{pmatrix} $

$=\frac{ 1 }{ 2^{n} } \sum_{i=0}^n \begin{pmatrix} n \\ i \end{pmatrix} \frac{ 2 }{t+1  } \begin{pmatrix} n \\ t \end{pmatrix}  \left\{ K_{t+1}(i)K_{t}(a)-K_{t}(i)K_{t+1}(a)    \right\} \sum_{k=0}^t{ \frac{ K_{k}(i)K_{k}(a) }{   \begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix}  } }$

Can somebody help me compute $\lambda_{0}$?

Comment: Use the orthogonal property of Krawtchouk polynomials. One term will cancel completely (cause there is no $k=t+1$) and the other term will give you the $-$ sign.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ive tried to solve it for several days, I also used the orthogonal property. Somewhere Im doing a big mistake but I cannot find the way out of this.

Comment: Thank you a lot !!

Comment: Sure, I have written it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you have that $$\lambda _0 = \binom{n}{t}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}(t+1)}\sum _{k=0}^t\sum _{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}\left (K_{t+1}(i)K_{t}(a)-K_{t+1}(a)K_{t}(i)\right )\frac{K_{k}(i)K_{k}(a)}{\binom{n}{k}}.$$
Notice that I changed the order of the sums. Take out the dependence on $k$ from the sum of $i$ and distribute to get
$$\lambda _0 = \binom{n}{t}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}(t+1)}\sum _{k=0}^t\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}\sum _{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}\left (K_{t+1}(i)K_{t}(a)K_{k}(i)K_{k}(a)-K_{t+1}(a)K_{t}(i)K_{k}(i)K_{k}(a)\right ).$$
Now distribute the sum to get two sums
$$\sum _{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}K_{t+1}(i)K_{t}(a)K_{k}(i)K_{k}(a)=K_{t}(a)K_{k}(a)\sum _{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}K_{t+1}(i)K_{k}(i)$$ and
$$-\sum _{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}K_{t+1}(a)K_{t}(i)K_{k}(i)K_{k}(a)=-K_{t+1}(a)K_{k}(a)\sum _{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}K_{t}(i)K_{k}(i).$$
These are the Orthogonal identities*, so for the first one you get $0$ because there is no $k=t+1$(notice that $k\leq t$) and the second sum is just $K_{t+1}(a)K_{k}(a)2^n\binom{n}{t}$ just when $k=t$. This means that the whole sum evaluates to
$$\lambda _0=\binom{n}{t}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}(t+1)}\sum _{k=0}^t\frac{-K_{t+1}(a)K_{k}(a)2^n\binom{n}{t}\delta _{k,t}}{\binom{n}{t}}=-\frac{2}{t+1}\binom{n}{t}K_{t+1}(a)K_{k}(a)=-\frac{2}{t+1}\binom{n}{t}K_{t+1}(a)K_{t}(a).$$
That is it.

Orthogonal identity* $$\sum _{i = 0}^n\binom{n}{i}(q-1)^iK_r(i)K_{s}(i)=q^n(q-1)^r\binom{n}{r}\delta _{r,s}.$$

Comment: Really, thank you so much... I used the orthogonal identities - but for any reason i didnt write down the $\delta_{r,s}$. 
When i saw it in your post, I was confused first - now i noticed that I completly missed that... 
Thank you so much - without your help i would keep trying to solve the problem the next days...

Comment: @malilini You are welcome. If you are satisfied, perhaps you can accept the answer for other users to know that this has been resolved. For that click the mark on the left of the answer.